# Is there a way to copy random files from source to destination?

Tags: python

I am working with 257 folders that contain images. I would like to copy 80% of the images of each of my folders and copy them into a new folder called Training. The 20% remaining images in each of the 257 folders would be copied to a new folder called Test. At the end, I would have two new folders Training and Test, where Training contains 80% of randomly selected images from each of my 257 folders while Test would have 20%.

Is there any Python function that can achieve this ? I did some research and all I found was the function shutil which copies all the files from a source to a destination folder.

Thank you

Comment: Think about how to break the problem down.

Comment: I achieved this with bash scripts in the past. You might want to look into something like that.

Comment: Look up os.listdir, random, os.mkdir,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a script like the following:

```
import os
import shutil
import random

SOURCES = [...]  # autogenerated or predefined constant

TRAINING = "Training"
TEST = "Test"


def main():
    os.makedirs(TRAINING, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(TEST, exist_ok=True)

    for src_dir in SOURCES:
        files = os.listdir(src_dir)
        random.shuffle(files)

        sep = round(len(files) * 0.8)

        for file in files[:sep]:
            shutil.copy(
                os.path.join(src_dir, file),
                TRAINING,
            )

        for file in files[sep:]:
            shutil.copy(
                os.path.join(src_dir, file),
                TEST,
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Beware that files with the same filename are silently overwritten when copied to the same destination.

Comment: Maybe refactor the two ˋround()ˋ calls into to a variable like ˋsplit_point = 4 * len(contents) // 5ˋ and remove the ˋlengthˋ variable? Should be clearer and cleaner. The colons sometimes slip attention, then the second loop looks like a copy & paste error (which it is not).

Comment: @Dilettant, thank you for the comment. I agree with you - this is a better way. So, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Demian and Team. Working now, you`re awesome :-)

Comment: @Faisal, I was glad to help you. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I ended up using (Thanks to Demian for the input):

```
#import libraries
import random
import shutil
import os

# Creating a Training and Testing folders
os.makedirs('Training')
os.makedirs('Testing')

basepath='C:\\aaa\\bbb\\257_ObjectCategories\\'
folders=os.listdir(basepath)

for folder in folders: # loop over the 257 folders
   contents = os.listdir(os.path.join(basepath, folder)) 
   random.shuffle(contents)  # shuffle the result
   split_point = round(0.8* len(contents))
   for img in contents[:split_point]:
       shutil.copy(os.path.join(os.path.join(basepath, folder), img), os.path.join("Training", img))
   for img in contents[split_point:]:
       shutil.copy(os.path.join(os.path.join(basepath, folder), img), os.path.join("Testing", img))
```